# Hyper-V virtual machine recognizes a new network at almost each start

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have several virtual machines in Windows 10 Hyper-V (Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 10 Ver. 1703 Build 15063.0).

- Both of them have two virtual network adapters each, all **with static MAC addresses**.
- Windows Server 2012 R2 behaves normally, without any surprises.
- Windows 10 constantly detects a new network ("Network 11", "Network 12", "Network 13" etc) for one of network adapters, almost at each VM start. For other network adapter everything remains as configured.

What is the reason? Could it be because it is a not activated trial version of Windows 10?

[image: New network notification]

Comment: Server 2012 is based on Windows 8 and is older. Try setting up the Windows 10 machine as DHCP on the internal NAT network and it should find the same network each time.

Comment: Did you mean windows 10 host or windows 10 VM will constantly detect a new network? If you mean windows 10 VM, which switch did the VM connect to? internal switch or external switch? If you remove the switch and then re-add again , will the issue still happens?

Comment: @John: Then the host will be behind the NAT too.

Comment: @Candy: Win10 VM. Internal switch -> NIC1 -> Ok. External switch -> NIC2 -> new adapter each time.

Comment: There should be an internal NAT setting independent of host.